# Dialogflow dont recognize phonenumber

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

Im tring to create a booking system for a restaurant so the assistant go to ask to user number of guest, time and day to reserve, and finally the name and the phone number of guest! But many time the phonenumber is confused by the guest number.
I set in parameters for @guest the value of #sys.number and for $telephone the entity of @sys.phone-number, but sometimes get wrong recognize. I could make it work?

Comment: Your request is not very specific. You may have better luck getting a response by uploading your fulfillment code, and by adding the actions-on-google tag. There are also several codelabs to help you get started with the Google Assistant: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0

Answer (score 1):

The Dialogflow team has a really full-featured example on Github [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-bike-shop-nodejs) (it's a bike shop, rather than a restaurant, but most of the functionality is the same). Give it a look for some inspiration.

Regarding the specifics of recognizing phone numbers: I'd recommend adding a bunch (like more than 10) of example training phrases to the appropriate Intent that include phone numbers. Often the problem with matching these things is just a matter of the number of examples the system gets to learn from.

Good luck!